# Implement backend client web app to store the secret info in Aouth

Tags: php, android, oauth

am building an Android oAuth client application.So i have a user data API link and.I generated the client _id and the client _secret String from the web site(Resource owner side).I have lots of quarries about the oAuth implement.The API web site built on the larevel php framework..So these are my quarries,

- Why we not Store client key and secret key in the mobile app.
- how to implement another back-end client to Store the secret_key and other information.(Using laravel framework).
- How to call the mobile client ->web client->and Resource server to exchange the access_token.

these are my really big problem.i read lot of articles but i cant get a proper information from that.if anybody can help me  and  provide any use full resources or tutorial it's very valuable help to me.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Before understanding this Clientid and Secret Just understand basic encryption methods for what this secret are used.

I would recommend you to understand **public key encryption** and **private key encryption** first. How many keys are there and how the encryption occurs.

You also need to understand how **digital signature** works and why we need this.

Probably you will get more idea why we are storing secret key and how it should be stored.

Comment: Why we use encription methods?client id and client secret only use for the identification am i right?

Comment: Ultimately these are your two keys. They are used for not only identification, But authentication, integrity and all.. And these are the aspect of public key encryption.

Comment: Just check how you are generating Client id and Secret.

Comment: ok normally i generate client _id and client_secret from the web site(ex :like when we create a developer account i the facebook)..

Comment: Accually i want to implement a web API to the store these  client_key....so after that i wanto create connection between these three app.(my android app->backend client web app->?and web api_)

Comment: Yes. got you. Even to develop API you need to know about this. Though you will need this in Mobile as well later on.